# podman pull on win 10 fails with temporary failure in name resolution

Tags: windows-10, podman

EDIT
issues pulling images on podman  windows  10 wslv2

podman machine start
Starting machine "podman-machine-default"
API forwarding listening on: npipe:////./pipe/docker_engine

Docker API clients default to this address. You do not need to set DOCKER_HOST.
Machine "podman-machine-default" started successfully

podman machine ls
NAME                    VM TYPE     CREATED            LAST UP            CPUS        MEMORY      DISK SIZE
podman-machine-default  wsl         About an hour ago  Currently running  8           642.8MB     584.1MB

podman run ubi8-micro date

Resolved "ubi8-micro" as an alias (/etc/containers/registries.conf.d/000-shortnames.conf)
Trying to pull registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8-micro:latest...
Error: initializing source docker://registry.access.redhat.com/ubi8-micro:latest: pinging container registry registry.access.redhat.com: Get "https://registry.access.redhat.com/v2/": dial tcp: lookup registry.access.redhat.com: Temporary failure in name resolution

C:\Users\user1>ping registry.access.redhat.com

Pinging e40408.d.akamaiedge.net [23.50.233.112] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 23.50.233.112: bytes=32 time=46ms TTL=56

Comment: It doesn't look like there is a question here.

Comment: solved with answer below please see it doesnt work with network issue

Answer (score 7):

credit to github user lleongl  podman issue containers/podman/discussions/16693#discussioncomment-5337355
solved with below

```
wsl -d podman-machine-default
sudo tee /etc/wsl.conf << EOF
[network]
generateResolvConf = false
EOF
sudo rm -rf /etc/resolv.conf
echo "nameserver 1.1.1.1" | sudo tee /etc/resolv.conf
```

Comment: You might want to add the first part of the URL leading to the comment that help you. Right now, it's just the subpath I can see.

Comment: for reference on windows 11 I had to use `sudo rm -rfi /etc/resolv.conf`

Answer (score 0):

Please update your topic with more details, it is very unclear what exact issue you are facing.

Assuming you are getting issues with Podman installation on Windows, first check this information at https://podman.io/getting-started/installation:

> Windows On Windows, each Podman machine is backed by a virtualized
> Windows System for Linux (WSLv2) distribution. Once installed, the
> podman command can be run directly from your Windows PowerShell (or
> CMD) prompt, where it remotely communicates with the podman service
> running in the WSL environment. Alternatively, you can access Podman
> directly from the WSL instance if you prefer a Linux prompt and Linux
> tooling.
>
> See the Podman for Windows guide for setup and usage instructions.

If the problem remains, check the full guide on Github:

https://github.com/containers/podman/blob/main/docs/tutorials/podman-for-windows.md

Comment: I answered question with solution